# ESP8266 Repeated Crashing When Pulling JSON Information

Tags: esp8266

I am trying to create a simple LCD device that pulls a random Jeopardy question from here: http://jservice.io/api/random, then cycles through the category/value, clue, and correct question at the push of a button. However, I am running into problems when I pull the clue. I am running this on an AdaFruit Feather Huzzah esp8266, but the board repeatedly crashes before returning the GetJeopardy function. In particular, I get errors like this:

```
--------------- CUT HERE FOR EXCEPTION DECODER ---------------

 ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:2, boot mode:(3,6)

load 0x4010f000, len 3584, room 16 
tail 0
chksum 0xb0
csum 0xb0
v2843a5ac
~ld
```

The function is as follows:

```
typedef struct {
  const char* cat;
  int val;
  const char* clue;
  const char* corr;
} jeop_problem;


jeop_problem GetJeopardy(){
  jeop_problem JQ;
  const size_t bufferSize = JSON_OBJECT_SIZE(2) + JSON_OBJECT_SIZE(3) +
                            JSON_OBJECT_SIZE(5) + JSON_OBJECT_SIZE(8) + 370;
  DynamicJsonDocument doc(bufferSize);
  if (WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.println("Pulling Jeopardy");
    HTTPClient http; // Object of class HTTPClient
    WiFiClient client;
    http.begin(client, "http://jservice.io/api/random");
    int httpCode = http.GET();
    deserializeJson(doc, http.getString());
    http.end(); // Close connection
    const char* cat = doc[0]["category"]["title"];
    JQ.cat = cat;
    Serial.println(cat);
    int val = doc[0]["value"];
    JQ.val = val;
    Serial.println(val);
    const char* clue = doc[0]["question"];
    JQ.clue = clue;
    Serial.println(clue);
    const char* corr = doc[0]["answer"];
    JQ.corr = corr;
    Serial.println(corr);
  }
  else {
    // We don't have a connection, return blank problem
    JQ = {"ERROR: RESET", -1, "ERROR: RESET",
                                    "ERROR: RESET"};
  }
  Serial.println("Pulled Jeopardy!");
  return JQ;
}
```

In particular, the board is always crashing *before* printing "Pulled Jeopardy" to the Serial console.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I should have mentioned, it does get through all the Serial.println(corr); but does not get to Serial.println("Pulled Jeopardy");

Comment: To be sure any of them were reached, you'll want a following `.flush()` call.  Otherwise it may crash/reset immediately afterwards and you wouldn't know the difference.  Put differently, without a `.flush()` after, `Serial.println("Pulled Jeopardy");` you can't be as sure that it didn't actually get to that line.

Comment: I don't know how your code relates to your [reset cause](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp8266_reset_causes_and_common_fatal_exception_causes_en.pdf).  It's possible that it doesn't at all.  But so long as you're providing information about where it hangs, it might as well be as accurate as possible.

Comment: the responses are over 1kb, how will that fit in such a small buffer? try a 4kb buffer (you have an 8266 here, not an UNO ;) )

Comment: I had the same issue caused by definition of StaticJsonDocument<200> jsonDoc inside a function. When I moved the definition as a global variable (out of the function) the problem was solved. I would suggest to try moving DynamicJsonDocument doc(bufferSize) out of the function.